# How do I delete a key in a plist if I have the key value?

Tags: applescript, command-line, plist

I have a plist like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Delete Me</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>Keep Me</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How do I delete the key-pair "Delete Me"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
defaults delete /path/to/file Delete\ Me
```

FWIW, I'd avoid having spaces in the keynames. You could try single quotes instead of escaping it.

Also: you don't need the file extension .plist in the filepath.

Alternatively, you can open it in BBEdit or Xcode *(both of which will handle conversion to and from binary plists on the fly)* and delete the relevant portion (`key` and `string`) directly. Other text editors may also do the same.

Comment: I can't verify the result after running that command because it changed the format of the plist to bplist. Do you know a way to keep it as XML text?

Comment: You can verify it with `defaults read`. It should return that the key is not found. Or, see my additions to the answer. For what app/process is this plist? Can the process read it as binary? There is the `plutil` command for converting the format.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I just got plutil to convert it back to text.
`do shell script "plutil -convert xml1 '<posixPath>'"`

Comment: Is this part of some larger process? Other solutions to the broader problem might be possible.

Comment: It's part of a library script. I have a session.applescript that I don't use directly, it has `setValue`, `getValue`, and now I want to have a `deleteValue` handler. It's used by other standalone scripts to store some current ID/value, for example.